# Firestore Integration Issue: Java.lang.VerifyError with WriteResponse after Updating Dependencies

Tags: kotlin, gradle, google-cloud-firestore

I recently integrated Google PALM (Generative AI) into my Android project, and while I successfully resolved Gradle issues, I'm now encountering a runtime error when trying to access Firestore. Here's the error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.abschlussprojekt_husewok, PID: 9114
java.lang.RuntimeException: Internal error in Cloud Firestore (24.9.1).
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue.lambda$panic$3(AsyncQueue.java:545)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$$ExternalSyntheticLambda6.run(Unknown Source:2)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:958)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8176)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971)
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Verifier rejected class com.google.firestore.v1.WriteResponse: void com.google.firestore.v1.WriteResponse.mergeCommitTime(com.google.protobuf.Timestamp) failed to verify: void com.google.firestore.v1.WriteResponse.mergeCommitTime(com.google.protobuf.Timestamp): [0x13] register v3 has type Precise Reference: com.google.protobuf.Timestamp but expected Reference: com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite (declaration of 'com.google.firestore.v1.WriteResponse' appears in /data/app/~~md4krpcTAky3hlN6rQM4-Q==/com.example.abschlussprojekt_husewok-LWjkjHC96uRzspkDd5k0Pg==/base.apk!classes16.dex)
    at com.google.firestore.v1.FirestoreGrpc.getWriteMethod(FirestoreGrpc.java:386)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.WriteStream.<init>(WriteStream.java:74)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.Datastore.createWriteStream(Datastore.java:143)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.RemoteStore.<init>(RemoteStore.java:193)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.MemoryComponentProvider.createRemoteStore(MemoryComponentProvider.java:103)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.ComponentProvider.initialize(ComponentProvider.java:153)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.FirestoreClient.initialize(FirestoreClient.java:296)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.FirestoreClient.lambda$new$0$com-google-firebase-firestore-core-FirestoreClient(FirestoreClient.java:114)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.FirestoreClient$$ExternalSyntheticLambda14.run(Unknown Source:8)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue.lambda$enqueue$2(AsyncQueue.java:444)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.call(Unknown Source:2)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$SynchronizedShutdownAwareExecutor.lambda$executeAndReportResult$1(AsyncQueue.java:330)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$SynchronizedShutdownAwareExecutor$$ExternalSyntheticLambda2.run(Unknown Source:4)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:487)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:307)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:644)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$SynchronizedShutdownAwareExecutor$DelayedStartFactory.run(AsyncQueue.java:235)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
```

Here is my current Gradle configuration:

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
    id("kotlin-kapt")
    id("com.google.gms.google-services")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.abschlussprojekt_husewok"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.abschlussprojekt_husewok"
        minSdk = 26
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isShrinkResources = false
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }

    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            exclude(group = "com.google.firebase", module = "protolite-well-known-types")
            exclude(group = "com.google.protobuf", module = "protobuf-javalite")
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "17"
    }

    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }

    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.4.3"
    }

    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
            excludes += "META-INF/INDEX.LIST"
            excludes += "META-INF/DEPENDENCIES"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    // Local unit tests
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")

    // AndroidX/Jetpack libraries
    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.2")
    implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.7.2")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:2.6.2")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-compose:2.6.2")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.7.4")
    implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout-compose:1.0.1")

    // Compose
    implementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.05.01"))
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material:material:1.5.4")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest")

    // Coroutines
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.6.1")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.6.1")

    //implementation("com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.23.2")
    implementation("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.11")
    implementation("io.grpc:grpc-protobuf:1.46.0")
    implementation("io.grpc:grpc-stub:1.46.0")
    implementation("com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.22.3")
    //implementation("com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.19.2")

    // Google PALM Generative AI
    implementation("com.google.cloud:gapic-google-cloud-ai-generativelanguage-v1beta3-java:0.0.0-SNAPSHOT")
    implementation("io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:1.53.0")

    // Retrofit
    implementation("com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0")
    implementation("com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-moshi:2.9.0")

    // Moshi
    implementation("com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin:1.15.0")

    // Firebase
    implementation(platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.5.0"))
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-auth")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-storage-ktx")

    // Third party libraries
    implementation("com.github.omkar-tenkale:ExplodingComposable:1.0.1")
    implementation("com.github.JaberAhamed:CardScratch:1.0")
    implementation("com.github.esatgozcu:Compose-Rolling-Number:1.0.5")
    implementation("com.exyte:animated-navigation-bar:1.0.0")
    implementation("com.github.popovanton0:heart-switch:1.4.0")
    implementation("com.github.SimformSolutionsPvtLtd:SSJetpackComposeSwipeableView:1.0.1")
    implementation("com.github.Spikeysanju:MotionToast:1.4")

    // Testing
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
    androidTestImplementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.03.00"))
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4")
}
```

I suspect that the issue might be related to the changes made during the implementation of Google PALM. Any help or suggestions on resolving this Firestore integration problem would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Why not directly use [Chatbot with PaLM API](https://extensions.dev/extensions/googlecloud/firestore-palm-chatbot)? Here is also a [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-create-a-chatbot-with-firebase-firestore-and-palm-on-android-e78549814aa) for Android.

Comment: My app has also received crash reports with this error (on a OnePlus 6). I'm not using Google PALM or anything like that.

Comment: you have any solution for this error?